# Doubt: Area between two curves

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider the parabolas $$f(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2} - 1$$ and $$g(x) = x^2 − 4x − 1$$
Sketch the graphs of these
two
functions and determine the area between these two curves in the interval $[0, \tfrac{8}{3}]$.

I was unsure which function to put first in the formula $$\int_a^b[f(x)-g(x)]dx$$ If the function on top $$-\frac{x^2}{2} - 1$$ or the function that is furthest from x.

Comment: Have you tried plotting them?

Comment: Let $F(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}-1$ and $G(x)=x^2-4x-1$. Then, the graph of these two functions intersect at $x=0,\frac{8}{3}$. Hence, the interval $[0,\frac{8}{3}]$. Now, can you determine if $F(x)\ge G(x)$ or $F(x)\leq G(x)$ in that interval? The choice of the first function should be clear after this.

Comment: The answer is that it really should not matter, as one would be the negative of the other. Hence, the simple answer is $\int_a^b\ \bigg|f(x)-g(x)\bigg|\ dx$.

Comment: Check to see whether the two functions intersect inside the given interval. If so, then you will have to break the integral into more than one part at the intersection point(s).

Comment: Pick any number in the open interval $(0,8/3)$ and evaluate $f$ and $g$ there. Whichever one returns the greater result will be your "first" function.

Comment: To @GabrielleSantos: I believe how all comments above were helpful for you. Next, since in your task you have to sketch the graphs of given function, i.e. two parabolas, do that step first. Sketching parabolas should be easy task. You can quickly determine a vertex for both parabolas, their (possible) intersections with $x$-axis, as well as which one is open upwards and which one is open downwards. It will be great help for your next step...

Answer (score 0):

firstly, lets look at the functions, the highest order term (greatest power) in both functions is $x^2$ so we call them quadratics:
$$f(x)=-\frac{x^2}2-1$$
notice that this is equivalent to:
$$-\frac12\times x^2-1$$
Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is negative you can remember that it forms a sad face, like so:
[image: plot of -x^2]
Now lets find the roots so we know what $f$ looks like:
$$-\frac{x^2}2-1=0\\
-\frac{x^2}2=1\\
x^2=-2$$
now this has *no real roots* in other words it does not cross the $x$ axis. Additionally, notice that if you put a negative value for $x$ it is equivalent to the same magnitude positive value i.e. $f(-x)=f(x)$, this is called an even function and means the function is symmetric about the $y$ axis. Additionally, notice that $f(0)=-1$ so the $y$ intercept is $-1$. You should get a plot like:
[image: plot of f]
Try and use this same technique to work out what $g(x)$ will look like.

---

To work out the area between the two curves we first need to know the domain. This will be the values of $x$ bounded by the intersection point of the two curves. Since we are dealing with quadratics there can be a maximum of two intersection points. To work these out set the functions equal:
$$f(x)=g(x)\\
-\frac{x^2}2-1=x^2-4x-1\\
\frac32x^2-4x=0\\
x\left(\frac32x-4\right)=0\\
x=0,\frac83$$
So we now have the two intersection points. Looking back at our functions we can see that over this range $f(x)\ge g(x)$. However, it is worth noting that area can only meaningfully be positive and so regardless of which function you put first, you simply take the positive (absolute) value. It is worth noting that:
$$\int[f(x)-g(x)]dx=\int[-[g(x)-f(x)]]dx=-\int[g(x)-f(x)]dx$$ and so the only difference between the order you choose is the sign. That said, if you want the value of the integral to be positive simply choose the order of functions that gives a positive value over the domain i.e.
$$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$
$$h(x)\ge 0\forall x\in\left[0,\frac83\right]$$